# Testing Angular Material DataSource sort

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-material, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit test a component with a sorting functionanlity for a DataSource provided by Angular Material. My test currently looks the following:

```
it('should contain a sortable table', (done) => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      const tableRows = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('tr');
      const sortButtons = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('button.mat-sort-header-button');
      expect(sortButtons.length).toBe(2);
      sortButtons[0].click();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      tableRows.forEach(row => {
        console.log(row.cells[0].innerHTML);
      });
      done();
    });
});
```

The sort buttons are found and the click also works as it seems like but the output in the console is not as expected. It is kinda not updated..

When running the app via ng serve the sorting works good. But here the sorting does not work as expected or my test seems to not register the changes made in the DOM? How can I implement this test properly?

Sorting function looks the following:

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item: DaResult, property: string) => {
  switch (property) {
    case 'da':
      return item.da;
    case 'currentcomponent':
      return item.componentCurrent.partNumber;
    default:
      return item.da;
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you show the sort function?

Comment: @PhilippEscher : Can u put some `console.log` in the `sort` function and see if it getting triggered from test case using `.click()` ?  Please confirm