# Jasmine, clicking a div with 'button' role

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a `mat-table` in an angular component, it uses `matSort` in the headers and i would like to test that my table is changed after clicking on the sorting option.

```
 it('Should properly sort table', () => {
        const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
        const table = compiled.querySelector('table'); 
        const buttons = compiled.querySelectorAll('div.mat-sort-header-container');
        buttons[0].click();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const reCompiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
        const sortedTable = reCompiled.querySelector('table');
        console.log(table === sortedTable); //Returns true
    });
```

[Unlike other questions similar to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250154/testing-angular-material-datasource-sort), i found out that my button is not a real html button but a div with role 'button':
[image]

My suspect is that the button is not clicked because the table is not changed after the clicking. 
Any tip is welcome